# Are dereferenced values of a global/local struct pointer always set to 0 (or equivalent) by default?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I know that global/static variables are by default set to 0 or equivalent in C.

How about a pointer to a struct?

For instance, consider the code below -

```
typedef struct meh
{
    int * ptr;
    int a;
    char c;
}var;

var *p;

int main(){
    p = malloc(sizeof(var));
    var *p1 = malloc(sizeof(var));

    printf("%d\t%p\t%c", p->a, p->ptr, p->c);
    printf("\n%d\t%p\t%c", p1->a, p1->ptr, p1->c);

    return 1;
}
//Output for both cases : 0 (nil) '\0'
```

Are dereferenced values for a struct pointer always set to 0 irrespective of the scope of the pointer? or is there a more specific rule at play here.

Comment: The dereferenced value of a pointer is whatever it points to. Whether it's initialized depends on how that object is created. If it's global or static it will be zero-initialized.

Comment: A global pointer is set null by default.  Each of the elements of a global structure is set to 0 by default.  Inside a function, neither pointers nor structures are initialized by default — unless the variable is `static` in which case the same rules apply as for global variables.  In this context, file scope `static` variables count as 'global'.

Comment: Since you're creating the dereferenced value with `malloc()` the value is unspecified.

Comment: @Barmar so in this example, p1 is a pointer in the local scope. However even its values are initialised to 0, is that a just a coincidence, I mean would it have been equally likely for dereferenced values of p1 to have garbage values?

Comment: The scope of `p` is irrelevant. You're assigning it the result of `malloc()`, so all that matters is how `malloc()` initializes the memory that it allocates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory returned by the `malloc` function is *uninitialized*.  Whether the returned pointer is assigned to a local variable or a global variable doesn't matter.

This means the pointed-to objects have **indeterminate values**, and reading them can cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you used the `calloc` function to allocate memory, the returned memory has all bytes set to 0.  This means that integer types will have the value 0.  Floating point types will also be 0 *if* IEEE754 representation is used, and pointer values will be `NULL` *if* a null pointer is represented as all bytes 0.  On most systems you're likely to come across this will be the case, but it's not true in general.

Comment: Re “This means that integer and floating point types will have the value 0”: Where does the C standard says the value of a floating-point object shall be zero when all its bits are zero? (It says this for integers in C 2018 6.2.6.2 5.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I could have swore there was something in the standard that dictated that.  I must have saw phrasing for integers and though it applied to floating point as well.  Edited to clarify.